# Passing an array as a parameter using jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working with Laravel 5.3 and Jasper reports as my reporting engine. I am using [phpjasper](https://github.com/PHPJasper/phpjasper) as my library. I am using my code to compile and execute my .jrxml files. How do I get to pass arrays as parameters so that I can do a query such as `SELECT * FROM fund_sources WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)`?

Comment: You should use `$X{}` expression and parameter of Collection type